# How to get a string field value via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have this method that returns a list of Fields objects that are of String type.

```
    public static List<Field> getStringFields(Class<?> clazz) {
        List<Field> toReturn = new ArrayList<Field>();

        Field[] allFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field f : allFields) {
            Class<?> type = f.getType();
            if (type == String.class) {
                stringFields.add(f);
            }
        }

        return stringFields;
    }
```

And this method, that should captalize all the string fields:

```
public void capitalizeStringFields() {
    List<Field> stringFieldsToCapitalize = Utils.getStringFields(someClass.class);
    try {
        for (Field field : stringFieldsToCapitalize) {
            field.set(this, field.get(this).toString().toUpperCase());
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is: the "field.set(...)" is not working. It supposed to capitalize the value and set it as the new value for that field, but it's not working... Any idea of how can I solve this? (PS: In the real code the "someClass.class" is set as the real class name...)

The error being generated is IllegalArgumentException in the field.get(this) method (insde the field.set method).

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Is the capitalize method in the class "someClass" or elsewhere?

Comment: What **exactly** is going wrong? "It's not working" is not a good way for others to help you. Please read: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry guys. I edited the text, I think that this is more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a number of things. If you are getting an exception when doing the "get" or "set", it might be because the field is private.

You need to do...

```
field.setAccessible(true)
```

...before anything else in that case.

It also looks like you want to call "get" and "set" on the same object as where the method is because you used "this"...

```
field.set(this, field.get(this).toString().toUpperCase());
```

(You are getting an IllegalArgumentException because it looks like you have got the fields for one type of class and you are trying to use them against a different class - e.g. the class that *this* is an instance of)

If you want a utility function to capitalise all of the String fields of a particular object, you could do something like this below. Before that though, I'd advise that this isn't very object-orientated because by using reflection like this, you are breaking the "encapsulation" principle of OOP...

```
class Utils {
    public static List<Field> getStringFields(Class<?> clazz) { ... }

    public static void capitaliseEverythingInADodgyNonOOPWay(Object changeMe) {
        for(Field field : getStringFields(changeMe.getClass())) {
            // Add try catch etc...
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(changeMe, field.get(changeMe).toString().toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Will not work with static String fields in the target class (you probably won't want to change those anyway...)

Comment: Also, getStringFields will not list all of the String fields in a type if there is a super type containing strings

Comment: Hi Bret and thank you for your answer :)

About that method is not being very object-oriented, what should be the proper way to accomplish this task as a object-oriented way? Putting some context to my question, the problem is that I need to capitalize all texts of a specific page (that have its fields contained on it MB class) before save it. The other way to do it, instead of by reflection way, I think, is setting listeners for each field on the xhtml file, but I'm trying to avoid it. Any idea? Ty!

Comment: @chr0x When you say "in a page", do you mean a JSP or some other template? If so, it sounds like a presentation layer concern. If you are using taglibs, then you could use this function... http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_touppercase.htm - just my opinion (it might be a pain if you've got to change loads of JSPs though)

Comment: I will try to test with JSTL, but seems that it will only change the info on the screen. I have to change the value on my backing bean to uppercase.

Comment: @chr0x if you have GOT to convert them all to upper case in the bean, the "clean" way would be to have a method that mutates the private fields explicitly. I can see that this would be a pain if you have to do it for hundreds of classes...